# How can i check a Line contains a special chracter?

Tags: java, utf-8, special-characters, inputstream, nio

Hi I have a file stored in Linux system that contains a special character ^C
Something like this:

ABCDEF^CIJKLMN
Now i need to read this file in java and detect that there is this ^C to make split.
The problem that to read the file in UNIX.I must use cat -v fileName to see the special chracter ^C elsewhere i can't see it.
This is my sample code.

```
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(this),
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("^C")) {
            String[] split = line.split("\\" + sepRecord);
            System.out.println(split);

    }
```

Comment: "^C" is just a representation of the character. It's not really a caret followed by a "C". You have to use its Unicode code. You did not mention what `sepRecord` is. Also, you can't print an array using `println` directly. You have to use `Arrays.toString`.

Comment: the special character is shortcut for control key, right?

Comment: http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html
check for the ascii code. it is 94. Let me know too

Comment: @v0ld3m0rt this is totally wrong in this specific case. The caret (`^`) is not a single character in the file, but `^C` is a control character noted in caret notation. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the line contains the **String** "^C", not the **character** '^C' (which corresponds to `0x03`, or `\u0003`). You should search for the character `0x03` instead. Here's a code example that would work in your case:

```
byte[] fileContent = new byte[] {'A', 0x03, 'B'};
String fileContentStr = new String (fileContent);
System.out.println (fileContentStr.contains ("^C")); // false
System.out.println (fileContentStr.contains (String.valueOf ((char) 0x03))); // true
System.out.println (fileContentStr.contains ("\u0003")); // true, thanks to @Thomas Fritsch for the precision

String[] split = fileContentStr.split ("\u0003");
System.out.println (split.length); // 2
System.out.println (split[0]); // A
System.out.println (split[1]); // B
```

The `^C` character is displayed in [Caret Notation](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_character_representation.html), and must be interpreted as a single character.

Comment: Instead of `String.valueOf ((char) 0x03)` you could simply use `"\u0003"`.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch True, I have updated my answer with your comment, thanks for the reminder!